# Set PagerTabstrip to bottom of screen

Tags: android, pagertabstrip

Generally PagerTabStrip appears at the top of screen just below appbar, Now I want PagerStrip to be at bottom , how can I set it to bottom of screen?
Help me out..
Code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/main_container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AppHomeScreen"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<include
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
    />
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/content_container">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#0ff"
                android:id="@+id/pager_tabs"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                >

            </android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip>
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:name="neppro.com.busapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Now, this is latest updated code of mine where I have used Relative layout  for viewPager , but I already have tried using LinearLayout also.

Answer (score 1):

Set the layout_gravity attribute on your PagerTabStrip to "bottom"

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
```

Comment: can you paste your layout file into your question please